# ASP.NET Core redirect or rewrite based on current domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, url-rewriting, content-management-system

I have a website with multiple hostnames which are used as different environments. I'll call them

- qa1.cmsSite.com
- qa2.cmsSite.com
- qa3.cmsSite.com

There is another internal application that uses a similar qa environment structure. I'll call them

- qa1.exampleApp.com
- qa2.exampleApp.com
- qa3.exampleApp.com

The cmsSites use the same content database so I can't create specific content for each environment. But I would like to ensure that if an end user is browsing on qa1.cmsSite.com and they click on a link to exampleApp, they would be directed to `qa1.exampleApp.com`. Similarly, if they are browsing on `qa3.cmsSite.com` and click on a link to exampleApp, they would be directed to `qa3.exampleApp.com`.

What is the best way to achieve this in C#/ASP.NET Core?

I'd rather not do it at the server level, so I'll rule out IIS configuration to handle the redirect. I'm thinking to maybe do this in `startup.cs` or in `appsettings`, but I'm not sure of the best approach, rewrite or redirect? extension method or middleware? Permanent or temporary? Do I need a regex?

Answer (score 0):

I think its easier to use javascript, but you can create a middleware to achieve.
CustomMiddleware.cs

```
    public class CustomMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl().Contains("qa.exampleApp.com")) //to check if request URL is your button link
            {
                string requestDomian = httpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"];   //get "https://qa1.cmsSite.com"
                if (requestDomian != null)
                {
                    requestDomian = requestDomian.Split('/')[2];      //get "qa1.cmsSite.com"
                    var initialWords = requestDomian.Split(".")[0];    //get "qa1"

                    httpContext.Response.Redirect("https://"+ initialWords+".exampleApp.com");
                }
            }
            
            
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    // Extension method used to add the middleware to the HTTP request pipeline.  
    public static class CustomMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();
        }
    }
```

To use in program.cs

```
app.UseCustomMiddleware();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Thanks Qiang. This is awesome. I'm still using startup.cs the old .net5 way. When i put app.UseCustomMiddleware() in the Configure() method of startup.cs, it seems to work for internal links only. In other words if i'm clicking links that keep me within cmsSite.com the code will pass through the request pipeline and execute code within CustomMiddleware.cs. However, if I click a link to exampleApp.com it just goes straight there without passing through the request pipeline (my breakpoint is never hit).

Comment: @MikeLowry Oh, my bad.  An external domain request won't even pass through the program.  I think you have to handle that link at front-end.  Or if you are using IIS, you can make URLrewrite rule to rewrite the exteral link URL request to internal, then it can pass through the pipeline.  Or just use internal link directly?